# Node Postgres Pub/Sub - remaining connection slots are reserved

Tags: javascript, postgresql, socket.io, node-postgres

I've built a notification system with node-postgres and socket.io. The system works alright, however, I am getting an error on startup.

> remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

I suspect this is due to not releasing the client back to the pool.

```
Pool.connect()
    .then(client => {
        return client.query('LISTEN "new_notification"')
            .then(result => {
                client.on('notification', data => {
                    // Handle the notification
                });
                // Should release here
            })
            .catch(e => {
                // Should release here
                this.log(e.message, 'error');
            });
        })
    .catch(e => {
        this.log(e.message, 'error')
    });
```

However even after adding `client.release()` in the locations where `// Should release here` are marked I still receive the error message. The notification still works, though.

When the server starts it creates a single `HeyListen` object in which the `Pool` above is created as well.

Now, the above error *usually* happens when the server starts and is flooded with connections. There are 6 sites that handle connections with users. Each user spawns a new connection to the socket.io server and when the `disconnecting` event is triggered via socket.io they are removed from a list of connected users. Each time a user connects they trigger a query against postgres if they have outstanding notifications. Here's the query object:

```
const conn = this.getConnectionType(pool);
conn.connect()
    .then(client => {
        return client.query(query_string, params)
            .then(result => {
                client.release();
                callback(null, result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                client.release();
                callback(error, null);
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        callback(error, null);
    });
```

If I run `Select * From pg_stat_activity` on my psql server I see:

[image]

I thought using `client.release()` was supposed to remove these connections? Rerunning the query above shows different query results so some are being removed. Is this an issue of not having enough `max_connections` available? If so is it a good idea to bump that number up for my use case?

Answer (score 1):

While experimenting with my own pub/sub client functionality for Node.js and PostgreSQL, I've seen that error when I run out of usable connections. If I remember correctly, the problem you're running into is that with the `node-postgres` package, a connection being used with `LISTEN` is considered active and in-use by the underlying connection pool until the client stops listening with `UNLISTEN`.

However, if you stop listening on a given connection, you'll no longer receive those useful `notification` events. Bit of a dilemma.

If possible, I'd advise you to look into setting up a smaller number of dedicated connections specifically for listening to various channels through PostgreSQL in each of your six applications, and then use separate connections to execute your additional queries. I don't know how feasible or performant this would be with your current traffic load, but in theory it should reduce the likelihood of using all available connections from the pool.

Out of curiosity, what was your rationale for having each user's connection `LISTEN` for notifications all on its own? It's possible to [pass a payload to listeners](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) through `NOTIFY`, so if you have some means of identifying an individual user, you could send your six apps a payload that declares which user a notification is for, and each of your six apps could forward that information to the correct user connection.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. There's a single `Listen` that is called when the server starts that stays open for the duration the server is running. When a user connects I use the event to let the server know they are there and any time the single `Listen` receives a new record it checks the connected user list, and if they are a part of that notification, it sends it to them.

Comment: Oh! Somehow I missed that. I apologize. That definitely doesn't account for why so many connections are remaining in use. I don't suppose you've tried querying directly from the pool and letting the pool manage obtaining/releasing client connections just in case it handles whatever edge case you seem to be experiencing here, have you?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I wanted to split the actions when a new `new_notification` event is triggered out of the pool so it wasn't all in one spot. You know, easier to read, lo.